# How can i ping remote computer on my Windows computer with c++?

Tags: c++, ping, winsock2

I used below code. It works, but in debug mode in Visual Studio if you stop the debug the computer gave blue screen so it is not useful. I did some research and i found this is a common bug for icmpapi. Is there a any way to ping computer c++?

```
        #include <winsock2.h>
        #include <iphlpapi.h>
        #include <icmpapi.h>

        //Declare and initialize variables
        HANDLE hIcmpFile;
        unsigned long ipaddr = INADDR_NONE;
        DWORD dwRetVal       = 0;
        DWORD dwError        = 0;
        char SendData[]      = "Data Buffer";
        LPVOID ReplyBuffer   = NULL;
        DWORD ReplySize      = 0;

        QByteArray ipArray   = computerIt->GetIP().toLocal8Bit();
        const char *hostIP   = ipArray.data();

        ipaddr = inet_addr(hostIP);
        if ( ipaddr == INADDR_NONE ) 
        {
            EventLogger::LogMessage(true, "<%s> Computer in <%s> Computer Group, IP initialization failed. (inet_addr(hostIP))", computerIt->GetName().toUtf8().constData(), computerGroupIt->GetName().toUtf8().constData());
            break;
        }

        hIcmpFile = IcmpCreateFile();
        if ( hIcmpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        {
            EventLogger::LogMessage(true, "<%s> Computer in <%s> Computer Group, IcmpCreatefile returned error", computerIt->GetName().toUtf8().constData(), computerGroupIt->GetName().toUtf8().constData());
            break;
        }

        // Allocate space for at a single reply
        ReplySize = sizeof (ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof (SendData) + 8;
        ReplyBuffer = (VOID *) malloc(ReplySize);
        if ( ReplyBuffer == NULL )
        {
            EventLogger::LogMessage(true, "<%s> Computer in <%s> Computer Group, unable to allocate memory for reply buffer", computerIt->GetName().toUtf8().constData(), computerGroupIt->GetName().toUtf8().constData());
            break;
        }

        // Starting pinging
        dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho2(hIcmpFile, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                ipaddr, SendData, sizeof (SendData), NULL,
                                ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 1000);
        if ( dwRetVal == 0 )
        {
            computerIt->SetAliveStatus(false);
        }
        else
        {
            computerIt->SetAliveStatus(true);
        }
```

Comment: You would have to create a RAW socket (which is restricted to admins only) and implement ICMP yourself.  The purpose of MS's icmpapi is to handle that for you while removing the admin restriction. Can you cite your sources that claim this is a known bug in icmpapi?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0d616a2-a1ea-43fb-831c-b1f51a957639/icmpsendecho-blue-screen this is the show the bug! How can i implement RAW socket it is so complicated can you show me an example!

Answer (score 3):

be careful.
at:

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx

the code works , BUT is  missing an IMPORTANT POINT if you paste/copy this code:
MISSING free(ReplyBuffer)