# Get ping without opening external program/window c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am attempting to get the ping of a client without opening an external program/window.
This is only meant for Windows machines.

It is supposed to run in a loop, so using something like `system("ping 8.8.8.8")` won't work, as it keeps on opening a new window. Are there any good and fast methods out there for something like this?

Comment: Does this anwer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32179834/4117728

Comment: you need use [`IcmpSendEcho2Ex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho2ex)